# How can I create a cookie for array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

How do I create and read a value of array of objects from cookie in JavaScript?

```
[{name="sss", age="33"}
, {name="ll", age="22"}]
```

Comment: i have a project which i suppose to save data in table and this data in an object has e- mail and age ..etc , it's contact APP  so i want when add new person to save his data , and i can not do this , when i search i also find just cookie for names    ,,,,  not = it's : sorry for this error

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to "stringify" the array and store the string in the cookie, something like:

```
var myArray = [{name="sss", age="33"} , {name="ll", age="22"}];
var cookieStr = JSON.stringify(myArray);
// Do whatever you want with your cookie
```

Then you get the string back out later (as a string) and parse it:

```
var cookieStr = ...; // Get it out of the cookie
var myArray = JSON.parse(cookieStr);
```

Comment: ok how can i loop on it , i have a large data

Comment: @mohamedosman: How to work with arrays is explained in the MDN JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Iterating_over_arrays